# code documentation for python

Tags: python, documentation, documentation-generation

What is out there on conventions and tools for documenting python source code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) is also a good tool for documenting source code, and handles cross-referencing classes, modules, variables, etc, into HTML, PDF, LaTeX. Draws some nice class inheritance diagrams too. It's used by a number of open-source projects, so it's fairly actively developed.

Answer (score 38):

Conventions: [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) and [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). 
Note, that docstrings can be written in [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)

Tools for generating documentation: for example [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Or, if you find yourself averse to reStructuredText, [pdoc](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc) also supports markdown and numpydoc docstring formats.

Answer (score 16):

First, put comments in your docstrings using RestructuredText format.

Second, get [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).

Third, create an index that uses the [autodoc extension](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html).

Then, run Sphinx to get really nice documentation.

Answer (score 6):

It's very nice to put code documentation in the code itself. See:

- [PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)
- [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

using doxypy filter with doxygen is a good thing also